# IllegalArgumentException while converting java.util.Date to org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: jodatime, java.util.date

I want to calculate the number of days, months and years between two Dates so i use JodaTime. I can get the result perfectly if my dates are in type of **org.joda.time.DateTime**. However the date inserted by the user is in type of **Date** ( format "yyy-mm-dd" ) and i use this type and this format in the whole project. so I write this code :

```
 Date d1=new Date("2013-09-11"); 
       Date d2=new Date("2014-12-12"); 
       DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
       DateTime dt2=new DateTime(d2);
       CalculCalendar clcd=new CalculCalendar(dt1,dt2);
       System.out.println(clcd.getNbjours(dt1, dt2)+" "+ clcd.getNbmois(dt1, dt2)+" "+ clcd.getNbyears(dt1, dt2));
```

When I run it, I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Date.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at CalendarDemo.main(CalendarDemo.java:50)
```

CalendarDemo.java:50 refers to : **Date d2=new Date("2014-12-12");**

How to resolve this problem without changing this format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't in conversion form JDK Date to Joda DateTime at all.  It's in parsing a string to a JDK Date.

```
Date d2=new Date("2014-12-12");
```

is a deprecated constructor call.  You probably should either use a [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to parse your datestring into a `Date`, or parse it straight to Joda's `DateTime` using its [parse](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter%29) method and a similar [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

These parsing methods allow you to specify the format you're expecting explicitly rather than depending on the default `Date.parse()`, which tries to figure out the format from the data.  Specifically why it's failing in this instance I can't say, but this is code you just shouldn't be using anyway.  It's been deprecated for years.